# How to reload TableView data from AppDelegate.m?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've tryed to reload TableView data from AppDelegate.m but with no success.

Here is code (whis is working in HomeViewController):

**AppDelegate.m**

```
...
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[self refreshTableData];
}

-(void)refreshTableData{

    UINavigationController *navController = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    HomeViewController *home = [[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MYTable" inManagedObjectContext:home.context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderEnt" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

    [request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *results = [[home.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    [home setArr:results];

    //NSLog(@"%@", home.arr);//here is showed correct data

    home.context = self.managedObjectContext;

    [home.myTableView reloadData];


}
...
```

Does anybody know how to reload data from AppDelegate.m?

Comment: why are you trying to do that call in appdelegate?

Comment: `home.myTableView` is a valid object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableViewData) name:@"ReloadAppDelegateTable" object:nil];
```

in your `viewDidLoad()` method and

```
- (void)reloadTableViewData{
  [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

in the class where you want to reload the Data.

Then you send a Notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadAppDelegateTable" object:nil];
```

whenever you want to reload the data.

**Note after some years of iOS development experience:**
While this is a very easy and comfortable solution, it is not 100% reliable. Notifications can be delayed by several seconds under certain circumstances. I would highly recommend to create a fast and reliable delegate connection to your `UITableViewController`.

---

Comment: this code is working but data in TableView is not changed. Have you any ideas why could be that?

Comment: everything is ok, it was my fault. I haven't connected od IB myTableView to outlet. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works well.. :)